# Accessing CSS calculated variable through Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

When working with `calc()`ulated properties in CSS, is it possible to access their expanded (i.e., actually calculated) values through Javacsript?

For instance, consider the following CSS:

```
:root {
    --ratio: calc(16 / 9);
    --width: 100px;
    --height: calc(var(--width) / var(--ratio));
}
```

And Javascript:

```
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
console.info(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('--height'));
```

One would expect to see `56px` being printed; instead, the string `"calc(var(--width) / var(--ratio))"` is returned.

Even if you try applying it to some CSS class property and reading from the class declaration instead, it won't work:

```
.rectangle {
    height: var(--height);
}
```

Javascript:

```
const rectangleClassDeclaration = /* find it through document.styleSheets */
console.info(rectangleClassDeclaration.style.getPropertyValue('height'));
```

And the console shows `"var(--height)"`.

So, is there a way to access the final, calculated value through Javascript?

Comment: The result is available when you apply it to an element, otherwise it's just an abstract notation. The engine won't apply name resolution and calculations unless you actually use a rule. From the documentation _"The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain"._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hack that I could think of is applying the value to some DOM element and them reading from it instead.

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
    height: var(--height);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const rectangle = document.querySelector('.rectangle');
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(rectangle);
console.info(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('height'));
```

And then you would see `56px` as the result. But this is kinda hacky, so it would be good to find out some way of accessing the variable's computed value directly. It works, anyway.

See [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/luciopaiva/pen/XaWWmZ) with working code.

Comment: _"But this is kinda hacky, so it would be good to find out some way of accessing the variable's computed value directly."_ Does your Answer resolve Question?

Comment: CSS variables are not supported in IE.

Comment: @guest271314 yes it does, although it would be nice to see someone giving a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, @Ihazkode. I'm not interested in supporting IE, though, so both my question and my answer still apply.

Comment: What do you mean by "more elegant solution"?

Comment: One that does not involve a hack. On the other hand, as @Axalix said, it looks like there isn't any other way of accomplishing this, so I'm gonna mark my own answer as the correct one, at least until something better appears in the future.